# Virtual Joint as part of planning group in moveit!

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I got my own robot into moveit! and added a planar virtual joint between my robots' base_link and odom like described in the PR2 tutorial. I created a group called 'complete' containing this virtual joint and the arm and would like moveit! to plan the driving path as well as the arm joints.
When I start moveit! it outputs this error in the terminal

> [ERROR] [1364401925.457291185]: Could
> not initialize chain object [ERROR]
> [1364401925.457352872]: Kinematics
> solver of type
> 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin'
> could not be initialized for group
> 'complete'

When I choose 'complete' as planning group in rviz and set the start state to random and press 'Plan and Execute" it works as desired and I can see it move to the goal state. My problem is that the interactive markers appear at the base_link and not the gripper which I think is due to the error posted above. If I use a planning group without the virtual joint, the markers appear at the correct position but moveit does not plan the driving path for obvious reasons.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59387/virtual-joint-as-part-of-planning-group-in-moveit!/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Kai,

<s>Could you please ask future MoveIt! related questions on the moveit-users mailing list: moveit-users@googlegroups.com. Its easier for us to track MoveIt! specific questions there.</s>

MoveIt! uses KDL for setting up the default kinematics solver. KDL does not support planar joints so that's why you are having trouble setting up a group like this. However, the fact that KDL does not support the planar joint only means that MoveIt! will not do the full inverse kinematics for you directly. You can still send individual joint values as a goal for the motion planning and MoveIt! will plan a path for you.

We will look into adding planar joint support into KDL in the future.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1